# Regular expression for the language accepting the strings containing at most one pair of $1$'s over $\{0,1\}$

Tags: regular-expressions

> Design a regular expression for the language accepting the strings containing at most one pair of $1$'s over $\{0,1\}$

So basically we have the language $L=\{11,011,110,0011,1100\ldots\}$.
I find the expression to be $R=(0+1)^*11(0+1)^*$.
But I found [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Egoodrich/teach/cs162/hw/HW2Sols.pdf) the answer to be $R=(0 + 10)^*(11 + \epsilon)(0 + 10)^*$.

I cannot differentiate these two answers and the logic behind the later answer.

**EDIT:** In my answer, the first $(0+1)^*$ may provide $11$, so after this another $11$ is not permissible since at most one pair of $11$ is required. But what's the logic behind $(11+\epsilon)$?

Comment: Your expression is wrong, $(0 + 1)^*$ means "0 or 1, as many as you like", so it includes e.g. $11$ or even $1111$.

Comment: The second answer doesn’t produce “1” on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind $(11+\epsilon)$ is to either allow a $11$, or allow no such pairs. The question states "[...] containing **at most** one pair [...]", and therefore we need to allow either one or zero pairs, and this is achieved by $(11+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Is the answer equivalent to $(10)^*+(01)^*+(10)^*1+1(01)^*+1(10)^*+(01)^*1+0^*(11)0^*$?

Comment: No, since $0$ wouldn't be generated by this expression

Comment: Then possibly $(\epsilon+0+1)(10)^*+(01)^*+(10)^*1+1(01)^*+(01)^*1+0^*(11)0^*$?

Comment: Still no, $1001$ wouldn't be generated.

Comment: isn't it necessary to have consecutive $1$'s to form a pair?

Comment: I think what you are doing is trying to "fix" your answer each time. This is a bad way of solving a problem, since it just makes your solution impossibly large and hard to understand, and also creates opportunity for additional errors. Instead, try to take a step back, and think of a solution back from square one.

Answer (score 1):

Although everyone seems to have given similar answers, I think $(0+10)^*(11+1+ϵ)(0+01)^*$ is the solution. On both sides, consecutive 1's should not appear, and in the middle, all cases that satisfy the condition of 'at most one pair' should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer itself is wrong (please correct me if not) because first  choose 0 from (0+10)* and 11 from (11+ε) so we get 011 and from the final (0+10)* if we choose 10 the final string becomes 01110 where we get 2 consecutive 1 pairs.
This may work: (0+10)* (11+ε) (0+01)*

Comment: A pity the question post does not contain an explicit question. nir shahar answered *What is the difference between $(0+1)^*11(0+1)^*$ and $(0+10)^*(11+ϵ)(0+10)^*$?* and *What is the logic behind the later answer?*, you take care of *What is a minimalistic expression for…?*.

Comment: The question is really unclear. Is 111 two pairs of 1s? 1111 surely is.

Answer (score -2):

0∗+(1+ϵ)(0+01)∗1(0+01)* might be the answer